# Convexity on large scales

Tags: convexity, convex-analysis

Has the following concept ever been studied/have a standard name?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We say $f$ is *(mid-point) convex on large scales* provided 
$$f\left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$ 
for all $|x-y|\geq 1$.

Comment: this sounds like the "modulus of convexity" for the function $f$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_and_characteristic_of_convexity